# List with dates, times and a string ref

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a sorted list of data to populate a gridview control.
The list is ordered by datetime

I need to find the most recent 3 times per unique ref within each day (there may be more than 1 unique refs within a day). If there is only 1 ref row within a day then it is to be ignored.

I suppose it needs to be chunked into days and refs, then ordered by most recent with a count of refs within that 'chunk'. Any ideas appreciated.

It's a standard list of objects (the object has Date, Time and Ref properties) as:

```
    private List<Reading> _listReadings = new List<Reading>();
```

and is bound to a grid:

```
    DataRow newRow = MyTable.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = new object[]
    {
        new 
        DateTime(_listReadings.TimeStamp.Year,listReadings.TimeStamp.Month),
        GetTime(_listReadings.TimeStamp),
        _listReadings.Ref,
    };
    MyTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Comment: Hi Martin, can you please provide us input in your question instead of snapshot and what output you are expecting? We would also interested in your attempts. What you tried so far? Did you face any error or issue?

Comment: Hi, I need to scan the list by date(day), then within each day, find the refs (3rd column) and if there are 3 or more rows, find the 3 most recent ones. If there are 2 or more refs per day then I need to find all 3 most recent instances. It's hard to explain fully!

Comment: How is your source data structured? Does your gridview control have an ItemsSource backing collection, which you can query (e.g. `collection.Take(3)`)

Answer (score 1):

- Given a backing source of `List<Reading>`,
- Group your source data by day using [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)
- For-each day (the value in the group):

  - Group your source data by ref using [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)
  - Test if the group has 3+ values, or filter the ones that do not ([Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) and [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1))
  - Order by datetimes of the values using [OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netcore-3.1) (latest is first)
  - [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1) 3 dates

So something like this:

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<Reading> Filter(List<Reading> readings)
    {
        List<Reading> result = new List<Reading>();

        var dayGroupings = readings.GroupBy(r => r.Day);
        foreach (var dayGroup in dayGroupings)
        {
            var refGroupings = dayGroup.GroupBy(g => g.Ref);
            foreach (var refGroup in refGroupings.Where(g => g.Count() >= 3))
            {
                result.AddRange(refGroup.OrderByDescending(g => g.Time).Take(3));
            }         
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. It's a standard list of objects (the object has Date, Time and Ref properties) as private List<Reading> _listReadings = new List<Reading>();

Comment: Thankyou kjhf, this looks very close to what is required. The power of LINQ!